# Sorting by Version Number in Maven Repository Manager UI

Tags: maven, artifactory, nexus, nexus3

My experience: Neither Nexus 2 nor Nexus 3 nor Artifactory are able to sort versions of artifacts correctly in their UI.

Versions are always sorted as Strings, which means that you easily miss versions like 2.11 because they come before 2.9.

Is there any way in any of the three respositories to get a semantic order scheme for versions (in the UI)?

Comment: Not a full solution for your problem since, yeah, ui tends to do do lexicographic string ordering - but in Artifactory you can use the [Package Search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Searching+for+Artifacts#SearchingforArtifacts-PackageSearch) to see maven (or any other) version sorted correctly.

Comment: I went to Package Search, chose Maven and searched for log4j. Then I ordered the table by "Version". Still, I get the lexicographic ordering on versions.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of NXRM3?  Do you have the problem on both tree view and search?

Comment: Newer version: Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.38.1-01 still has this problem